# Is there a website that tracks fare deals from any airport in the world?

Tags: budget, flight-search-engines

I got really excited when I read the promise of the website *farealerts.co*, but then I realized it only includes a few airports from the US and I don't live there.

Do you know of something similar for any airport in the world? I have seen alerts in different search engines like kiwi.com, but you would have to create several alerts for each destination. The idea here is to only have to set the "home" airport, just in case there is a great deal to an unexpected place.

Comment: If you type the airport name you actually have access to lots of airports in the UK, France and Germany. Note that bizarrely enough you need to type the name of the airport, not the city or the airport code. It also costs US$49/year, and given they will only send you alerts if the price goes down by 60% I wouldn't be surprised if you never received any alert. Due diligence advised.

Comment: At a first glance, this looked like 'spam' promoting a for-profit site. Can you rewrite it to make it less advertising-like?

Comment: When I tried it from the US it only offers small airfields. I highly doubt it would work from a larger airport with many 100s if not 1000s of potential destinations. Also the criteria is weird. 60%  down from a ridiculous price might still be very expensive, whereas 20% of an already attractive price may be a winner. A threshold would be better, I think

Comment: @Hilmar it is really very weird. My initial thought on reading the question was that they only had small airports because that made it possible to actually try to track fares from those (if you only take into account direct flights of course), but LHR, LGW, CDG, FRA, DXB, DUB, LAX are in there and many more. On the other hand, can't seem to find JFK, EWR, LGA, MIA, SFO, SIN, HKG, AMS... Their search field gives the weirdest results. On the other hand, even though they send you to a payment page right away, you can actually register a single airport for free. We'll see how that turns out.

Comment: That site's search doesn't seem to be aware of airport codes or even the cities the airports are located in. I live near Atlanta, GA, so I naturally typed in "ATL" to search - but came up with little of use (just tiny airfields). Then I tried "Atlanta", and got some other airfields somewhere in Illinois  ... Eventually I typed in "Hartsfield", since that's the start of the actual name of the "real" ATL airport here in Atlanta, GA - and it then finally gave me the result I was looking for.

Comment: @jcaron If I type LCA (IATA) = Larnaca International Airport... Nothing shown. I guess it's good to know that it's not US only though. It's also good to know that it's not a free service... Anyway, my question is about if someone knows about a similar solution as this one is not working for me :)

Comment: @o.m. actually my original question has been edited by someone else, so it wasn't me . I think now it's less clear than the original question, but that's how this system works!

Comment: @Hilmar yeah, actually on the original question I think I didn't ask for 60% (but someone else rewrote the original question). Anyway the question is about if someone knows about a similar solution as this one is not working for me (and not 60% necessarily, again: someone rewrote the original question, feel free to rewrite again to something more clear if you consider) :)

Comment: @brhans thanks for sharing! I don't find anyway to see "Larnaca International Airport". I guess it's a new service with several bugs yet. Anyway just to clarify the question is not about testing this website (thank you anyway) but to ask the community about similar solutions... Because for me the idea is cool as I have the flexibility to travel anytime :)

Comment: @chelder the issue is that it’s probably quite difficult to track the numerous fares from one airport. If you combine the number of destinations and departures and return dates you quickly end up in the millions…